# How to skip bytes in a Stream

Tags: c#, io, stream

How to most efficiently skip some number of bytes in any [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx)?

If possible, I'd like to get or throw an [`EndOfStreamException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.endofstreamexception.aspx) when trying to skip past the end of the stream.

---

I am writing a custom stream `Reader` for ISO 9660 primitive data types, and this may involve a lot of skipping in seekable and non-seekable streams, both small numbers (4) and large numbers (2048) of bytes. Therefore I want to implement a `Skip(int count)` method that is a bit more efficient than reading and discarding the skipped bytes.

For example, in a [seekable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx) stream I might do `stream.Position += 4`, but this does not throw an `EndOfStreamException` when seeking past the end of the stream, and I don't know how to test for that without reading something. For non-seekable streams, setting `Position` is not even an option, but reading and subsequently discarding large numbers of bytes and allocating unused byte arrays seems very wasteful.

Comment: Frankly, I think what you have described (checking `CanSeek` and either using `Seek` or read+discard) is pretty much "it". Maybe you could risk reading `.Length` in the `CanSeek` scenario, but: you should exception-handle that too; I'm not sure that `CanSeek` *guarantees* a `Length` implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `stream.Position += 4` you can use `stream.Seek(4, SeekOrigin.Current);` which saves you one call to Win32 API.

You can always check against the `Length` property of the stream if it's supported. If it's not supported there isn't a way other than trying to read from the stream. Actually on streams where length is unknown, seeking is essentially reading.

If `CanSeek` is false, you can't read `Length` and vice versa.

About wasted memory during reading, you don't have to read amount of bytes you're skipping. You can allocate a fixed size of memory (large or small) and use it for any length you want. If you need to skip more than that size, you just read `x / size` blocks and read the remainder `x % size` bytes.

Comment: Are you sure that all seekable streams have a `Length`? And even if forward seeking is reading, you know of no way to prevent the allocation of byte arrays for non-seekable streams?

Comment: @Virtlink: pretty much. Quoting MSDN: "If a class derived from Stream does not support seeking, calls to Length, SetLength, Position, and Seek throw a NotSupportedException."

Comment: @Virtlink: I also added an edit to my answer about memory allocation problem. There are other low-level techniques too let me know if you're interested "that much" in saving memory.

Comment: I like your approach of allocating a fixed-size buffer and using that to read and discard the data. Accepted, until somewhere in the future someone knows of a better way to skip bytes.